# My div container covers the navbar when hovers after scaling property was added

Tags: html, css, github, flexbox, grid

I'm making a project for my coding Bootcamp, and they asked me to add transform: scale property onto the project cards. But after it was added, whenever I hover over the cards, it goes over the navbar.

Example of the hover property after scaling was added:

[image]

But if `transform: scale()` wasn't added, it doesn't happen. Can someone help me?

This is the Live link from Github pages.
https://adamteddychang.github.io/Hello-Portfolio/

Here is the code:

```css
.bk-img-proj {
  margin: 2rem;
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.bk-img-proj:hover {
  background-image: url(Images/bg-img-dsktop/hover-proj-img.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.08);
  transition: 50ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="bk-img-proj">
  <h1 class="bk-img-title">Progessional Art Printing Data</h1>
  <p class="bk-img-p">A daily selection of privately personalized reads; no accounts or sign-ups required. has been the industry's standard</p>
  <ul class="lang-contain_2">
    <li class="lang-li_2">html</li>
    <li class="lang-li_2">bootstrap</li>
    <li class="lang-li_2">Ruby</li>
  </ul>
  <button class="st-see-btn_2" type="button">See Project</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe CSS property transform-origin will help: `transform-origin: top center;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `z-index: 10` to your `navbar`.
That way it will always stay on top of your content!

Out of my head I can't really explain why you're having this issue but I do know that `z-index` will solve it.